# I have tried to propagate this Clematis by putting the dandelion-like seed in potting soil. It did not work

Tags: propagation

[image]This clematis develops dandelion-like seed puffs. Can I even propagate this by its seeds or is it some kind of sterile hybrid?

Comment: I scattered seeds from a native clematis ( mountanensis ??)  and it has been invasive . I am about the only person who notices the white ,fragrant flowers high in trees. I did not treat the wild collected seeds in any manner.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had forgotten all about stratification. This should help.

Answer (score 3):

It would be quite normal for the seed (in moist medium) to need to be refrigerated or placed outside to simulate or experience actual winter, so that it would know when spring was and it was time to sprout.

That process is called stratification. It's a biological safeguard for the seeds to prevent them making tender new plants just in time to be frozen, die, and not make more seeds to propagate the plant.

I'm not sure how difficult clematis seed is to propagate, (roots seem far more common in the trade) but that's a one typical reason that freshly collected seeds won't sprout.

Comment: I think the OP could have some success with stratification. My neighbor's Sweet Autumn Clematis is a weed in my yard, thanks to its abundant seeds, and I've had a Jackmanii reseed as well.

Answer (score 2):

How you propagate your clematis depends on the specific species it is.  [Here](https://gardenerspath.com/plants/flowers/clematis-types/#:%7E:text=for%20each%20group.-,Group%201,cleanup%20is%20all%20they%20need.) is a nice guide to help you identify your clematis's species.

As you said, some species of clematis are sterile and their seeds will never propagate.  As Ecnerwal said, other plant seeds will not germinate without proper [stratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratification_(seeds)).  A gardener took the time to experiment with germinating clematis seeds [here](https://www.gardenmyths.com/growing-clematis-from-seed/) where they tested different clematis species with different germination techniques and monitored the germination rate.  You can read through there for details on your specific clematis, or just take their general conclusion:

> Based on all of the references and the current tests, I would
> recommend the following as a general germination procedure for most
> clematis. Use the [baggy method](https://www.gardenerbasics.com/blog/germinating-seeds-with-paper-towels), warm, in the dark, with tails removed.
> If you have GA3 use it, but it is probably not required.

That same gardener references [this good germination resource](https://www.gardenmyths.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Deno-Seed-Germination-Introduction-min.pdf) from Dr.Deno.

If you're really adventurous, [this gardener](http://www.bcollingwood.com/Germination.htm) has also posted good information, but the website is a bear to read.